# why get this error - 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' when use ng2-bootstrap-modal in prod build?

Tags: angular

I have angular 4 project, and I'm using ng2-bootstrap-modal, in debug mode dialog works fine, but when I build in prod mode, start published application and click button to show dialog, get this error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at t.createDialogHolder (dialog.service.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:52)
    at t.addDialog (dialog.service.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:33)
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: You tagged this as `ngx-bootstrap-modal` but your question states it is `ng2-bootstrap-modal`... Which is it?

Comment: sorry for tag, I mean ng2-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Did you solved your problem? Getting the same here.

Comment: Yes I solved my problem, I make some fixes into library. I'll add all files below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change dialog.service,  this:

```
 let componentRootViewContainer = this.applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0];
```

by

```
let componentRootViewContainer = this.applicationRef.components[0];
```

Here is whole dialog, just copy and paste it:
https://ufile.io/m8qm2

```
in app.module
import { BootstrapModalModule } from './shared/dialog/bootstrap-modal.module';


imports: [
.....
    BootstrapModalModule,
....
]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 BootstrapModalModule.forRoot({container:document.body})
```

into your app.module

Comment: Strange...this seems to work in my dev mode. However, it doesn't seem to work in release mode. Anybody else had this problem? I can't use the workaround as suggested in accepted answer because my CI/CD auto-installs npm packages.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not good idea of managing npm packages to fix the issue.
We can add a constructor and one line in app module to consider components when it's referred to _rootComponents.

```
//change in app.module.ts
export class AppModule {
  constructor(applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {
  //for ng2-bootstrap-modal in angualar 5+(6, 7 etc..)
    Object.defineProperty(applicationRef, '_rootComponents', {get: () => applicationRef['components']});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In node_modules -> ng2-bootstrap-modal-> dist -> dialog.service.js

Change this.applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0] to this.applicationRef.components[0];

Answer (score 0):

`if locally work fine and not on server site then use below solution
go in node_modules -> ng2-bootstrap-modal-> dist -> dialog.service.js
and open dialog service and replace this code

let componentRootViewContainer = this.applicationRef['_rootComponents'][0];

by

let componentRootViewContainer = this.applicationRef.components[0];`

Answer (score -1):

These lines must be changed:

> node_modules -> ng2-bootstrap-modal-> dist -> dialog.service.js

and in

> node_modules -> ng2-bootstrap-modal-> src -> dialog.service.js